# Using NEVPNManager in iOS 8, How can I programmatically create VPN connections to custom VPN types? (e.g. Cisco any connect)

Tags: ios, ios8, vpn, nevpnmanager

Looking at VPN configuration in apple's Configurator tool, it offers many different types of VPN, such as

- L2TP
- PPTP
- Cisco AnyConnect
- Juniper SSL
- Check Point Mobile VPN
  etc

I'd like to create a custom VPN configuration programmatically using `NEVPNManager`, however looking at the [list of objects added in the NetworkExtension framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/NetworkExtension.html) there are only 2 protocol classes - `NEVPNProtocolIPSec` and `NEVPNProtocolIKEv2`.

I'm new to the world of VPN's, so my question is this:

Are those proprietary VPN types (such as Cisco AnyConnect) just variations of IPSec or IKEv2, and thus can I set them up using one of those protocol classes, or is it not currently possible to do this with NEVPNManager

Comment: Hi do you find a solution on this? I want to connect to Anyconnect programatically as well

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own version of VPN via NEVPNManager, but you can't use it to set up / edit other VPNs (such as Cisco).

Comment: I need to use Cisco any connect for the vpn..based in client requirement not looking for personal Vpn as option

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for requesting information about the Network Extension framework. Please note that as of November 10, 2016 this process is not required for developers who wish to use App Proxy, Content Filter, or Packet Tunnel APIs. To use these services please navigate to your Developer Account at https://developer.apple.com/account/ and select the Network Extension capability for the App ID you will be using for your app.

If you are requesting an entitlement for Hotspot Helper APIs and have already filled out the request questionnaire then your request will be addressed at our earliest convenience. Otherwise please visit https://developer.apple.com/contact/network-extension/ and enter the required information.

Regards,
Developer Technical Support
Apple Worldwide Developer Relations